# Is there a way to classify data points with python above a value and series threshold (consecutive numbers above the threshold)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, signal-processing, threshold

I am trying to classify data with python by first establishing a threshold then classifying it if it is above the threshold for a certain period of time.

Example data: *My value threshold is >4 and my series threshold is >2*

```
[5,5,1,1,1,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]
```

Expected output: *Note the first two values are zero because they do not meet the series threshold*

```
[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
```

So, I only want to classify the data as 1 when it meets both the series and value threshold.

*Does anyone know the best way to attach this problem with python?*

Comment: I get a different result following your directions. I get `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`. So for example, the last five values, only the three last values pass both tests, because for the first two values, the series test finds only one or two values which pass the value check. Either the example is wrong, or I'm misunderstanding your directions.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/whatisnumpy.html) in the following fashion:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([5,5,1,1,1,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5])
v_threshold = 4
s_threshold = 2

out = np.zeros_like(a)

out[s_threshold:] = a[s_threshold:] > v_threshold
#array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```